# Como mudar o data type na requisição $.post no jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

```
var envio = $.post("processamento/busca.php", { 
            unidade: $("#unidade").val()
            })
```

Tenho essa requisição, gostaria de alterar o datatype para json, no ajax tem um parâmetro datatype, mas não sei como utilizá-lo no $.post, se é que dá para utilizá-lo... Eu sei que é possível fazer com $.ajax, mas tenho tantos códigos em $.post que seria trabalhoso demais mudar tudo.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o método `$.post(url, data, success, dataType)`, você envia os parâmetros assim:

```
$.post('processamento/busca.php', { 
         unidade: $("#unidade").val() 
     }, function (response) {
         console.log(response); // aqui você vai tratar o JSON recebido
     }, 'json');
```

Esta forma é um atalho ao método `$.ajax` mostrado em outra resposta.

Answer (score 2):

O `$.post` é uma simplificação na sintaxe do ajax normal (exibirei logo abaixo), se não me engano não é possível passar essa opção em apenas um requisição, para resolver o problema eu aconselho você a utilizar da maneira abaixo.

```
$.ajax ({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({data:"test"}),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(){
        //
    }
});
```